# Heroku Cedar - no static assets for mounted Resque front-end

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, heroku, resque

I have a simple Rails app deployed to the Heroku Cedar stack.

The app uses Resque and the Resque Sinatra front-end app is mounted so I can monitor the queue:

```
# routes.rb
...
mount Resque::Server, :at => "/resque"
```

This works great, but when deployed to Heroku, the [Resque front-end's CSS & JavaScript](https://github.com/defunkt/resque/tree/master/lib/resque/server/public) are not being served.

A snippet of Heroku's logs indicates it's returning zero bytes:

```
...
2011-07-13T16:19:35+00:00 heroku[router]: GET myapp.herokuapp.com/resque/style.css dyno=web.1 queue=0 wait=0ms service=3ms status=200 bytes=0
2011-07-13T16:19:35+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2011-07-13T16:19:35+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2011-07-13T16:19:35+00:00 app[web.1]: Started GET "/resque/style.css" for 87.xx.xx.xx at 2011-07-13 16:19:35 +0000
2011-07-13T16:19:35+00:00 app[web.1]: cache: [GET /resque/style.css] miss
```

How can I get it to serve these assets?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try removing the route and mounting the app in your `config.ru`. I'm using something along the lines of:

```
require ::File.expand_path('../config/environment',  __FILE__)
require 'resque/server'

run Rack::URLMap.new(
    "/" => Rails.application,
    "/resque" => Resque::Server.new 
)
```

Answer (score 4):

Same as ezkl but password protected, works for me:

```
# config.ru
# This file is used by Rack-based servers to start the application.

require ::File.expand_path('../config/environment',  __FILE__)
require 'resque/server'

# Set the AUTH env variable to your basic auth password to protect Resque.
AUTH_PASSWORD = ENV['RESQUE_PASSWORD']
if AUTH_PASSWORD
  Resque::Server.use Rack::Auth::Basic do |username, password|
    password == AUTH_PASSWORD
  end
end

run Rack::URLMap.new \
  '/'       => MyApp::Application,
  '/resque' => Resque::Server.new
```

Comment: Thanks kain, good suggestion. However, I decided to keep my authentication defined in my resque.rb initializer, something like so:


`# use basic auth on the resque front-end
Resque::Server.use(Rack::Auth::Basic) do |user, password|
  password == "secret"
end`

Answer (score 0):

I believe it's necessary to set a root path, when deploying to heroku. For example, I boot a sinatra application by specifying

```
require './app'
run ExampleApp
```

in `config.ru`, and setting the root in `app.rb` thus:

```
class ExampleApp < Sinatra::Base
  set :root, File.dirname(__FILE__)
end
```

That solves the problem of static assets not being served in a sinatra application, for me.
For resque, perhaps you can extend the class and mount that instead, setting the root?

Comment: Thanks tiredpixel, it's good to know this option for the future.

Answer (score 0):

HEROKU Cedar stack and rescue need this line of code to prevent database connection failure.

```
Resque.after_fork = Proc.new { ActiveRecord::Base.establish_connection }
```

Above code should be placed in: `/lib/tasks/resque.rake`

For example:

```
require 'resque/tasks'

task "resque:setup" => :environment do
  ENV['QUEUE'] = '*'

  Resque.after_fork do |job|
    ActiveRecord::Base.establish_connection
  end

end

desc "Alias for resque:work (To run workers on Heroku)"
task "jobs:work" => "resque:work"
```

Hope this helps someone, as much as it did for me.