# Heroku how to setup resque web on a rails 3 app?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, heroku, ruby-on-rails-3.2

I have followed some guides on how to setup resque on heroku, but they are out dated.

My config.ru:

```
require File.dirname(__FILE__) + '/config/environment'
require 'resque/server'

Resque::Server.class_eval do

  use Rack::Auth::Basic do |email, password|
    user = User.authenticate( email, password )
    user && user.admin?
  end

end

app = Rack::Builder.new {
  use Rails::Rack::Static

  map "/resque" do
    run Resque::Server
  end

  map "/" do
    run ActionController::Dispatcher.new
  end
}.to_app

run app
```

In lib/tasks/resque.task:

```
require 'resque/tasks'

task "resque:setup" => :environment do
  ENV['QUEUE'] = '*'
end

desc "Alias for resque:work (To run workers on Heroku)"
task "jobs:work" => "resque:work"
```

I have added this to my gemfile:

```
gem "resque"
```

Then in initalizers/resque.rb:

```
ENV["REDISTOGO_URL"] ||= "mydatabaseurl"

uri = URI.parse(ENV["REDISTOGO_URL"])
Resque.redis = Redis.new(:host => uri.host, :port => uri.port, :password => uri.password, :thread_safe => true)
```

I am using to redistogo nano heroku addon.

On Heroku the app crashed with the error:

```
/app/config.ru:16:in `block (2 leve
ls) in <main>': uninitialized constant Rails::Rack::Static (NameError)
```

The rails version is `3.2.11`

Comment: Update to the lastest version please, 3.2.11 has a dangerous bug of remote code executing. Source: http://arstechnica.com/security/2013/01/extremely-crtical-ruby-on-rails-bug-threatens-more-than-200000-sites/

Comment: The solution is the answer on this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6682265/heroku-cedar-no-static-assets-for-mounted-resque-front-end

Comment: No, it isn't (that article doesn't say it, but I read it elsewhere).

Comment: 3.2.11 has some serious problems.  You will need to upgrade.

Answer (score 0):

It's not able to find the constant `Static` in the namespace `Rails::Rack`.

Try `Rack::Static`